Laravel/Filamentphp Save filled input on refresh
I am trying to save temporary data if someone will be do refresh on create page.
for example:
I trying create post and filled title, text,category and etc... and in my mistake I clicked refresh possible save old value ?  I searching on Google but I can't found this solution for Filamentphp
Searching google, asked CHATGPT

Have you tried localStorage?

@MustafaReda no I don't know how to save on local storage from filament
